# Detect the div hight relative to the window?

Tags: jquery

here is my jQuery code, i want to give the div#topImgs height relative to the window height, how it works ?

```
$("#topImgs").css("height", function(){
        $( window ).height();
});
```

Comment: You mean something more like `$("#topImgs").css("height", $(window).height() )` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to return the height of the window:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/632f4wpc/)

```
$("#topImgs").css("height", function () {
    return $(window).height();    /* Some calculation here.. */
});
```

```
$("#topImgs").css("height", $(window).height());
```

You may not actually need jQuery for this, though. In [supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), you can use [viewport-relative units, `vh`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ab3h0qk1/)

```
#topImgs {
    height: 100vh;
}
```